# is mouse wheel always button4 and button5 in xlib?

Tags: c, linux, mouse, xlib

I used xev on my system and mouse wheel up/down generates button4 and button5 messages respectively.  Now if I interpret these in my program I will get mouse wheel to work.  But will it always be button4 and button5?  If not how to get the buttons to which mouse wheel is mapped?

Comment: Buttons may be remapped by the user (see `xinput list` and `xinput get-button-map` for example).

Comment: Possible with xlib as well - core x11 SetPointerMapping request - http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XSetPointerMapping.html